# How to manage IPN url and notify_url

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

The account backend give you the ability to choose a url for IPN calls. That url is unique.
On the other hand, the html form has a notify_url parameter (i always used that one to structure my flows dynamics) and it can change based on some variables.

The question is: which is the bound between the two parameters URLs? If i set the notify url in the form, i should follow some good habits in choosing the IPN url in PP account backend? And vice-versa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPN URL set in the account is a default value for that account.

If a notify_url is set at the HTTP redirect/API/transaction level, it takes precedence over any value (or lack of a value) set in the account

So if you are setting something at the transaction level, you do not need to be concerned about what is set in the account.